# How can I sum all records in ZIM?

Tags: zim-database

Given the current data:

```
EXAMPLE_TABLE
ID      NAME            INITIAL_DATE        END_DATE        (END_DATE - INITIAL_DATE) + 1
1       Arthur          20150101            20150130        30
1       Arthur          20150301            20150305        5
2       Bianca          20150101            20150130        30
2       Bianca          20150301            20150306        6
2       Bianca          20150501            20150510        10
```

How can I group and sum up the results as the following, using ZIM?

```
ID      NAME            SUM
1       Arthur          35
2       Bianca          46
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXAMPLE_TABLE` must be first sorted on `NAME` (find example_table sorted by name) and then:

```
list all where $distinct(name) is not $null format id name $total(end_date - initial_date + 1)
```

Alternatively you could use `REPORT FROM` with `BREAK ON name ... FOOTING` to generate a similar list with subtotals.

Comment: Report from was a viable alternative, since I had to use BREAKs to sum days by "name".

In my case specifically, I used another software we had installed to export the data to Oracle and created a regular SELECT query to compute the results I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, sum((end_date - initial_date)+1) from EXAMPLE_TABLE group by id, name
```